# How to unit test aync Task without type

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await

I have `async` methods which doesn't have any return type , it just has `Task` type.

How can I write valid unit test method for just `Task` ?

**Async Methods:**

```
public async Task UploadFileAsync(FileDetails data)
{

   await _fileUpload.UploadImageAsync(data);

}


public async Task UploadImageAsync(FileDetails data)
{  

// does a async operation to upload a stream to azure blob storage

await azureBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(streamData).ConfigureAwait(false)

}
```

**Test Method:**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task UploadFileAsync()
{
    //-->Arrange

    _fileUpload.Setup(e => e.UploadImageAsync().Returns(new Task<Task>(() => null));

    //-->Act

    Task result = _uploadManager.UploadFileAsync(GetFakeUploadData());

    // Task doesn't return any result ?

    //-->Assert


}
```

Update:

Finally I call [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet) method to upload file to azure blob storage.

Comment: You need an `await` in your `UploadFileAsync()`: `await _uploadManager.UploadFileAsync(GetFakeUploadData());`. If it's just returning `Task` this is the `async` equivalent of `void`, so there is no result to check in your test

Comment: @Liam Ok but what result can I have from `Task` to Assert and check ?

Comment: There is no result. You can't test the result, it's basically `void`. So you need to figure out a different way to test....whatever it is your trying to test.

Comment: I presume there's more code here because this is currently only testing that your mock exists...

Comment: @Liam  Finally we call [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet) method to upload file to azure blob storage.

Comment: If you are setting  up `UploadImageAsync` via a mock then the azure call is a non factor in the test.

Comment: Feels a little like there is nothing to test here. If I were you I'd take a hard look at these tests and ask yourself, what does this actually test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just change your Act section to:

```
//-->Arrange

_fileUpload
    .Setup(e => e.UploadImageAsync(It.IsAny<FileDetails>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<object>((object)null))
    .Verifiable(); //<-- Allows you to verify that the mock was invoked correctly

//Act
await _uploadManager.UploadFileAsync(GetFakeUploadData());

//Assert
_fileUpload.Verify();
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the Moq framework.

Comment: Ok but what result can I have from `Task` to Assert and check ?

Comment: @stom You do not have enough details in the OP for us to be able to guess what it is you are trying to test. You could try verifying that the mock was called.

Comment: @stom - Your method doesn't return anything for you to then check. e.g. if you returned a boolean it's return type would be Task<bool>. Without the generic type, your method is a void with no return value.

Comment: FYI,   Finally we call [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet) method to upload file to azure blob storage.

Comment: Thanks , but what would be the test for invalid data or result ?

Comment: @stom again you do not have enough details in the OP for a reasonable answer to be provided to that question. Read [ask] so in future questions it can be clearer what is the problem to be solved.

Answer (score 3):

An async method returning `Task` is similar to a regular `void` method. You can await the task to ensure that the method runs before your test completes:

```
Task result = _uploadManager.UploadFileAsync(GetFakeUploadData());
await result.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

There is no assertion to make here - all you could say about the method is that it runs without triggering an error.

If the server returns some token to your application when upload is complete (say, some proprietary resource identifier) than it would be beneficial to change the signature of `UploadFileAsync` to make that identifier available to the caller:

```
public async Task<UploadedResourceIdentifier> UploadFileAsync(FileDetails data) {
    var ret = await _fileUpload.UploadImageAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return new UploadedResourceIdentifier(ret); // Parses the return, and constructs resource identifier
}
```

Now the test would have something to assert:

```
var result = await _uploadManager
    .UploadFileAsync(GetFakeUploadData())
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
Assert.That(result.IsValid, Is.True);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `ContinueWith` method so you can inspect the `IsFaulted` member.

```
result.ContinueWith(t => Assert.IsFalse(t.IsFaulted));
```

Comment: This very much depends on what that method does and what the OP is trying to test. This might be true, but it's just as likely that this won't achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
await _uploadManager.UploadFileAsync(GetFakeUploadData());
```

to execute the operation and wait for it to complete, and then you should somehow access the uploaded file and verify it's there. If you can upload you can probably also download, so use that.